# How to import visual c++ library into android studio project?

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, java-native-interface

I created a shared visual c++ cross platform mobile library in visual studio 2017 for iOS, UWP, and Android. I was successful able to create a Windows RT Component wrapper for the library to use in a C# UWP. I removed the iOS library as I did not need it. All that remain is the Android project. Currently I am struggling how to write a wrapper for the shared library and import it into android studio. I looked the documentation provided on MSDN, but it goes more in depth on creating a cross platform c++ application and not enough detail on how to leverage the shared static libs.

RandString.java:

```
package com.myapplication;

/**
 * Created by yorel56 on 7/26/2017.
 */

public class RandString {
    static{
        System.loadLibrary("libRandString");
    }
    public native String GetString();
    public native String GetString(int index);
}
```

[image: .so files produces by VS2017 project]

build.gradle (module):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs/' //integrate your libs from libs instead of jniLibs
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn(nativeLibsToJar)
    }

    task ndkBuild(type: Exec, description: 'compile native code') {
        def ndkDir = "C:\\Users\\yorel56\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk\\ndk-bundle"
        workingDir "src/main/jni"
        commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build"
    }

    task nativeLibsToJar(type: Jar, description: 'create a jar archive of the native libs') {
        destinationDir file("$buildDir/native-libs")
        baseName 'native-libs'
        extension 'jar'
        from fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '**/*.so')
        into 'lib/'
    }
    nativeLibsToJar.dependsOn {
        ndkBuild  // comment that, when you don't want to rerun ndk-build script
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/native-libs", include: 'native-libs.jar')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

The error i am getting currently is that 'native' is not allowed here, and when i choose to let Android Studio fix it by creating a function in native_lib.cpp, I continue to get errors. I tried following the documentation [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/04/18/android-and-ios-development-with-c-in-visual-studio/).

Comment: I am trying to utilize the VS templates for creating a c++ cross platform mobile shared lib, I was able to use the lib for a UWP project, but am having troubles following suite for Android. The documentation regarding this on MSDN leans more towards creating a full cross platform c++ mobile project which i am not. I am developing in native, but want a particular shared feature to be written in c++.

Comment: So, basically, you have a native Android Java app and you're trying to call out to the C++ library you wrote using JNI? What problems were you having with it? What did you try, and what went wrong? Can you create a [mcve] showing the relevant parts of your code and show any exceptions or error messages you were getting?

Comment: Correct, does the above help?

Comment: The C/C++ functions on the native side must be declared with some modifiers and with a special strict syntax. If you have not already done so you should install the Hello_JNI Android Studio example project or something similar and play with it

Comment: Yes, the edit is a big improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `libRandString.so` which was built with Visual Studio; you don't need the `externalNativeBuild` block and not `ndkBuild` task and not the `nativeLibsToJar` task in your **build.gradle**. Android Studio will pick up the prebuilt files from **jniLibs** directory and pack them into the APK for you.

Comment: I'm now getting the following exception  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError, stating librandstring.so could not be found

Comment: I hope the error message is for `libRandString.so` with correct capitalization. This would mean that you cleaned up your **build.gradle** a bit too much.