# Visual Studio 2017 shared c++ crossplatform lib integration in Android Studio via CMAKE

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio, mobile, cmake

After creating a prebuilt shared c++ library with Visual Studio 2017 i want to integrate that library into my existing android application. I compiled my shared c++ library with gcc 4.9 and i use Cmake as my build system in Android Studio.

The project itself is building and when i try deploying my .apk i get a linker error of the form

`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "ABSOLUTE PATH"`

As compiler in Android Studio (defined via gradle) i tryed clang as well as the same gcc i build the library with. From my CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library(libname SHARED IMPORTED) 
set_target_properties(vrcore PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${lib_DIR}/libname/lib/${ANDROID_ABI}/libname.so)

target_include_directories(app PRIVATE ${lib_DIR}/libname/include)

target_link_libraries(app
                  libname
```

I also read:
[How to import visual c++ library into android studio project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329576/how-to-import-visual-c-library-into-android-studio-project)

And did all according to the described 'Android NDK official hello-libs CMake example':
[How to link a prebuilt shared Library to an Android NDK project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870435/how-to-link-a-prebuilt-shared-library-to-an-android-ndk-project)

And can exclude a capitalization error. Additionally i already include thirdparty shared prebuilt libraries without any problems. I hope this sketches the whole problem, if you need any additional information let me know.

Comment: What value do you want to assign to `IMPORTED_LOCATION` property? Current code contains two values - `${lib_DIR}/libname` and `/lib/${ANDROID_ABI}/libname.so` - but you need to assign only one.

Comment: Sry this was my fault, they both belong together and build the relative path. ${lib_DIR}/libname/lib/${ANDROID_ABI}/libname.so